# 3 x 3 cell with large center layout with flexbox simple implementation ideas needed

Tags: css, flexbox

With CSS Grid, it's pretty easy to implement something like this [3 x 3 cell with large center with css grid](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOLPRV)

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;
}
```

Is there a simple way to implement this using flexbox?

[simple flexbox implementation?](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBvRWr)

Comment: why flexbox and not grid?

Comment: Not without defining a the height of the container.

Comment: I prefer grid but still not able to use it because of IE 11.  Just wanted to see if flexbox could be as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

---

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
}

.item {
 background-color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 12%;
  height: 30px;   /* (100-32*3)/2 */
}
.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: gray;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 70%;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 0 12%;
}
.item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 0 12%;
}
.item:nth-child(5) {
  flex: 1 70%;
}
.item:nth-child(8) {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 70%;
}
```